# change propagation rules and impact analysis

Tags: java, oop, modeling, uml

I am looking for some kind of propagation rules. Suppose I have a program model depicting different dependencies among parts of that program. Then one part is changed and I need to propagate that change and retrieve set of affected parts. Specifically I need to perform this for java programs.

I have already searched several articles for such information, but every time I meet only general words and nothing specific.

Hope I explained that clearly. I would be grateful for any information :).

Thanks.

Comment: This seems ultimately based on the structure of your program.  So unless you are asking how to structure your program it won't be possible for people to tell you how to pass data around.

Comment: @greedybuddha, undoubtedly affected parts depends on program structure, but also there are some similar cases that are applicable to any program. I do not need very specific behavioural impact analysis, just architectural

Answer (score 0):

The problem description is quite unspecific, but what might help you is the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Instead of each module having hardcoded "dependors", each module implements an "*Observable*" interface, by which any "*Observer*" (i.e. module) can (un-)register. If a change is detected, the concerned module can iterate of its registered observers and triggering their update()-method, allowing them to do their stuff and propagating the change to their observers as well, creating a cascade.